# Should I give money to my children?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim my child occasionally asks me for money, I usually give her 100 coins because I don't want her to strive to live, nor being "spoiled".
Jokes apart, is there any difference if I give more or less money to my children?

I know I can get [Gift of Charity](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/The_Gift_of_Charity) when gifting something to them.

Comment: Doesn't have any effect, it's just some RP flavor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I went to the trouble of digging out the source code for this interaction. Here is what happens if you give the child 25 gold:

```
Game.GetPlayer().RemoveItem(Gold001, 25)
akSpeaker.AddItem(Gold001, 25)
(GetOwningQuest() as BYOHRelationshipAdoptionScript).DecrementPoorCount(1)
FavorJobsBeggarsAbility.Cast(Game.GetPlayer(), Game.GetPlayer())
FavorJobsBeggarMessage.Show()
```

And here is what happens if you give the child 1000 gold:

```
Game.GetPlayer().RemoveItem(Gold001, 1000)
akSpeaker.AddItem(Gold001, 1000)
(GetOwningQuest() as BYOHRelationshipAdoptionScript).DecrementPoorCount(5)
FavorJobsBeggarsAbility.Cast(Game.GetPlayer(), Game.GetPlayer())
FavorJobsBeggarMessage.Show()
```

Points to note:

- The `DecrementPoorCount()` method is called with a larger number if you give the child more money. Looking through the file `BYOHRelationshipAdoptionScript.psc`, this does not appear to be used by that script directly, but it keeps track of how "poor" it thinks the player's family is, which can trigger altered dialog in some cases (according to the comments). This altered dialog also plays into the next bullet.
- The money is placed in the child's inventory (the child is `akSpeaker`). Again looking at the aforementioned script file, it appears that this money is subsequently "spent" on gifts the child purchases for the player in later interactions. The child selects from a different list of gifts depending on how much money they have. If the family is "poor" (i.e. if the player has repeatedly refused to give an allowance, or possibly if other interactions have raised the poverty counter), then a different procedure is used, which always selects from a fixed list of (presumably inferior) items and does not charge the child for the gift at all.

  - This does not use the regular vendor system. The selected gift is materialized out of thin air, and the money is deducted from the child's inventory directly.
- I believe `FavorJobsBeggarsAbility` is the internal name for The Gift of Charity.

In short: If you give your child more money, they are more likely to purchase more expensive gifts for you in subsequent interactions. If you refuse to give your child any money, they will still give you gifts, but of lower quality, and their dialog may acknowledge your supposed lack of money.

Comment: Now I get why they used to give me small potions and now I get golden jewelry instead :)